# Задать z-index для маркера карт Google

Tags: google-maps-api, javascript

Доделываю большой модуль. Столкнулся с такой бедой. На карте несколько маркеров, они выводятся динамически, в зависимости от области видимости. Хотелось бы при наведении курсора на маркер, устанавливать ему максимальный z-index. Т.е. выводить маркер на передний план. Событие наведения мышки отловить легко, а вот как установить z-index, пока загадка :( Кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей? Можно ли её решить без привлечения сторонних библиотек, типа prototype?

Answer (score 2):

Ну если Вы говорите, что событие отловить легко, тогда:

```
// Заводим переменную, в которой будем хранить индекс
var lastIndex;

// obj - объект маркера, отлавливаем наведение
obj.onmouseover = function(event) {
    var s = event ? event.target : window.event.srcElement;
    // получили в s объект на который было наведение
    lastIndex = s.style.zIndex;
    // запомнили его индекс
    s.style.zIndex = 100000;
    // поставили новый
}

// а тут при отведении мыши возвращаем индекс на место
obj.onmouseout = function(event) {
    var s = event ? event.target : window.event.srcElement;
    if (lastIndex) s.style.zIndex = lastIndex;
}
```

Comment: А если s заменить на this и вставить всё это в GEventListener?

Типа: GEvent.addListener(points[s],'onmouseover',function(){this.style.zIndex = 100000;})

Собственно так и отлавливаю наведение курсора.

Сейчас проверить, к сожалению, не могу :(

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, нужно менять только индексы.
Если удобнее для каждого маркера через GEvent - проблем нет.
Я же предлагаю решение через DOM, хотя разницы нет.

Просто ставь zIndex, но не забывай запоминать и сохранять zIndex при наведении, а при отведении возвращать на место, иначе когда ты наведешь на все маркеры - все элементы будут иметь один zIndex

Comment: Спасибо. Вечером попробую, отпишусь. Я планирую при каждом новом наведении увеличивать zindex. Т.е. при отведении восстанавливать не буду. Инофбалунов у меня не будет, так что можно и больше 1000 делать

Comment: Да, как вариант
this.style.zIndex += 1;
ну или если скосячит, то:
this.style.zIndex = 1 + parseInt(this.style.zIndex);